# How to validate whether a column exists in an excel?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

I have data stored in the excel file i have passed the attributes excelPath and sheet Name as well.
How to validate whether a column exists in an excel or not using PAF?

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom tag :

###getExcelColNumber, Att1=columnName, Att2=keyName
getExcelColNumber=com.tr.execution.activities.GetExcelColNumber

```
<activities>

<activity id="Validate_whether_a_Column_Exists_in_an_Excel">

             <getExcelColNumber columnName="Version_num" keyName="colNo" ></getExcelColNumber>

             <validation valGroupIds="ValidateColumn" ></validation>

</activity>

<valGroup groupId="ValidateColumn" >

              <validate variable="colNo" condition="equals" value="-1" passMsg="Pass" failMsg="Fail" snapshot="false"></validate>

</valGroup>

</activities>
```